# How do I pass a parameterized value to a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, xunit, fixtures, parameterized-tests

I'm using pytest to run tests, each with a unique account ID. Each test function requires some setup and teardown, and I switched to using fixtures according to previous suggestions. But now **I need to use the unique account ID associated with each test to correctly setup and teardown the test.** Is there a way to do this?

Also, I have some setup required on the session level and the class level, which is probably unrelated, but needed for the create_and_destroy_test function.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_env(request):
    test_env = "hello"
    return test_env

class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def parameters(self, test_env):
        print("============Class Level============)")
        print("Received test environment, ", test_env)
        parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        return parameters

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function')
    def create_and_destroy_test(self, parameters, test_env):
        print("============Function Level=============")
        print("Posting data") # Needs an account id
        print(test_env)
        print(parameters)
        yield parameters
        print("Performing teardown") # Needs an account id

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("account_id", [1111, 2222])
    def test_one(self, create_and_destroy_test, account_id):
        assert 0

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("account_id", [3333, 4444])
    def test_two(self, create_and_destroy_test, account_id):
        assert 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the test ID or the test name from the `request` object in your fixture. While there is no direct access to the parameter value, you can just access it by parsing the id or name, as it ends with the parameter value. So you can do something like:

```py
import re
...
    @pytest.fixture
    def create_and_destroy_test(self, request, parameters, test_env):
        match = re.match(r".*\[(.*)\]", request.node.nodeid)
        if match:
            account_id = match.group(1)
            # do something with the ID
```

Your test id will be something like `some_path/test.py::TestClass::test_one[2222]`, and by using the regex you get the needed parameter from the expression in the brackets, e.g. `2222`.